# Video Play Rotate Automatically

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-one, video-player, display-rotation

When I play a video(both in video player and browsers) on my ubuntu 18.04 TLS it runs smoothly but after a while the display reverse to it automatically.It happens each and every time I play videos.It is fully annoying.How to get rid of these problem?

Comment: What do you mean by '360 degrees'? It spins around? or do you mean it turns upside down, or rotates to one side at 90 degrees?

Comment: It rotates to one side I mean it reverses to it.